# Insert external DB in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm doing an application with alot of data in the database so I need to make an external database with SQlite browser and put it in my application

my problem is

I can't see data/data/database because my mobile isn't rooted and I can't root it for reasons

I'm using BlueStack emulator in Eclipse IDE

Please help

Thank you

Comment: There is no need for root to use SqLite in android apps.

Comment: With `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` you can determine the proper path to put the database. You application will need permission *READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* to read the data base and *WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create your database and put it in your assets directory
and on first use copy to data directory.

```
try {

    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
            + "/databases/YOURDbFileName";

    File f = new File(destPath);
    if(!f.exists()){
    Log.v(TAG,"File Not Exist");
    InputStream in = getAssets().open("YOURDbFileName");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destPath);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.v("TAG","ioexeption");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the external database into a folder that is accessible by the phone. So that you can manipulate the database from there.

new location must be: "/data/data/your.app.package/databases/yourdatabasename"

Comment: The usual extensions are `.db` or `.sqlite`.